# Laravel app.js not Found and npm run Failed in New Project

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-artisan

When I run `php artisan serve` in my new Laravel project, I get a blank page at localhost. The console says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` for my app.js. This is my app.js:

```
import './bootstrap';

require('./bootstrap');

require('./components/HelloReact')
```

What I've tried: Run `npm run dev`, upgrade npm to 16.11.1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a bit of confustion here with what you are actually using as the error mentions both a vite config as well as trying to include a laravel-mix file

Comment: @apokryfos I’m not sure what you mean - am I not supposed to have both?

Comment: No, older Laravel installations included Mix but newer ones come with vite. You can't use both (at least you're not supposed to). If you are watching an older tutorial then you could use older Laravel version which comes with mix. But I recommend going full vite for new projects.

Comment: @apokryfos OK Thanks, I think I resolved that issue. Now running `npm run dev` works, but I am still getting the original 404 error.

Comment: Add how you installed your project. Do you use the latest Laravel version with breeze starter kit? Did you install via composer + node for assets or sail? There are somethings missing in your question. As per @apokryfos said, dont mix both mix and vite.

Comment: Are you working on local or Server?